# startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance() deprecated

Tags: java

help
my problem is that it has become obsolete (startActivityForResult) how can I update it?

When generating the verification from the Firebase server, it asks the user for a Captcha validation

code

```
private void phoneLogin() {

    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setLogo(R.drawable.logo_inicio)
            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
            .setAvailableProviders(providers).build(),
            APP_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == APP_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error de ingreso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```